# PHP 5.3.10 connection with Sybase 12.5.4 using Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, sybase

I must connect my Zend Framework 1.11 application with sybase 12.5.4.

I need to know how to do that from Windows 7 AND from debian 6.

I had installed sybase client on my Windows and enabled the php_sybase_ct extension (sybase_ct appears on my phpinfo), but I even could connect with sybase_connect.

The following code:

```
$cnn = sybase_connect('server.com.br,port', 'user', 'psw', "iso_1", 'app');
sybase_select_db('db', $cnn);
```

returns an error:

```
sybase_connect() [function.sybase-connect]: Sybase: Unable to connect in C:\wamp\www\testesybase.php on line 3
```

Someone can, please, help me?

I've been looking for it for a looong time!

Thank you!

**Update:**

Since I got sybase_connect() connect working, now my issue is: How to make Zend Framework 1.11 connect on Sybase 12.5.4?

I read that PHP uses pdo_dblib - *PDO(sybase: ...)* - to do that, but PHP5.3.10 on Windows doesn't have this driver anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with Zend Framework by using PDO Driver for [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/)!

**FreeTDS installation**

You need to install *php5-sybase* (the Sybase connector provides the required libraries for connecting to the MSSQL Server and Sybase) and the *freeTDS* software and *unixODBC*.

To install and configure FreeTDS, see [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/21uxeq/connecting-to-a-mssql-server-database-with-php-on-ubuntu-debian).

Also, [this link](http://www.chandlerfamily.org.uk/2012/12/freetds-sql-server-from-debian-apache-php/) provides a good read about FreeTDS installation.

**Configuring a connection string and conecting with Zend Framework 1.11**

Configure your connection on `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`, like this:

```
[MyServer]
host = <<ip>>
port = <<port>>
# use 8.0 for newer versions of SQLSERVER
    tds version = 8.0
    # text size don't need to be such a high value, its just an example
    text size = 4294967295
    client charset = UTF-8
```

Then, on Zend Framework 1.11, configure your connection like this:

```
;; BANCO DE DADOS LINUX
database.adapter                = PDO_MSSQL
database.params.pdoType         = dblib

database.params.host            = MyServer
database.params.dbname          = <<dbname>>
database.params.username        = <<username>>
database.params.password        = <<passwd>>
database.params.driver_options.charset = UTF-8

database.isDefaultTableAdapter  = true
```

Comment: How can you do that? Can you explain it please?

Comment: @Guido, I added more details to my answer to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $cnn = sybase_connect('server.com.br,port', 'user', 'psw', "iso_1", 'app');
```

change this in

```
    $cnn = sybase_connect('server.com.br', 'user', 'psw', "iso_1", 'app');
```

Comment: what did the following code:

$cnn = sybase_connect('server.com.br', 'user', 'psw'); 

print_r(sybase_get_last_message());

Comment: it prints: `ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error: Requested server name not found.`

Comment: can you ping 'server.com.br' from your machine? i remember, in the past we had configured a FreeTDS Server on Ubuntu to connect to mssql-server. in the configfile [freetds.conf] we must have init the connection. eg [MyServer70] host = example.com port= 1433 tds version=7.0 client charset = UTF-8

Comment: I got the error! At my work we use a shared sql.ini with all the dsn. When I installed the Sybase Client my PATH change to the local sybase, so I copy everything on (server)/sybase/sql.ini to (local)/sybase/sql.ini. Then I could connect to sybase. =)

Comment: But I can't connect with Zend Framework yet! I'm using `resources.db.adapter                = PDO_MSSQL
resources.db.params.pdoType         = sybase` but it says `The sybase driver is not currently installed` What I have to do to connect?